# Insert an Identity Value using Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Note: This seems to have been asked indirectly several times, but never really answered.

I have a row that I delete using Entity Framework.  When I delete it I archive it in a different table.  In some cases that row needs to be restored to the table it came from.

But here is the kicker, I would really really like it to have the exact same ID it had when it was deleted (I actually need to restore rows from several tables that are FKed off this ID).

Is there **any** way to have EF put a row in with a specified Identity value (yet still remain an Identity for other inserts).

**If not** what would be a good way to work around EF to make this insert (realizing that my WCF app could be using EF to make inserts and updates to that table at the same time (though with different identities)).

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and Entity Framework 4.

Answer (score 0):

What other inserts would be going into this other table that require them to have their own IDs?

Anyway what you should do is have an IDENTITY column and a nullable int column that stores the ID of what that was when it was deleted. When that information is not relevant then you just don't populate that column.

Comment: The table is a normal activity table.  Think of it as a Client table.  New clients get added but when a deleted one gets re-activated, we want to keep the same info and history it had previously.  (Note: We are past the point of keeping an "Active" flag.)

Comment: Since you are using SQL Server 2008 R2, and depending on what you mean by "past the point", have you looked into filtered indexes? An index with a where clause of `Active = 1` that includes the columns you're typically after might make a very easy solution to the perceived problem, without introducing this "let's stuff deleted rows over in this table" complication.

Comment: The "past the point" refers to the many many lines of code that would have to be updated to deal with an `Active = 0` scenario.  Filtered indexes are a very nice feature, but they don't hide data, they just make getting data with specific characteristics faster (at least from what I have seen).

Comment: Right, I wasn't suggesting that a filtered index would hide data. Just that it would make it not ridiculous to query for relevant data only. Still I think you need to reconsider whether this ID you want to track needs to be in an identity column in the tracking table - as I suggested it will be much simpler to store the ID in a separate column that simply isn't populated when it's not relevant.