# Are there drawbacks to going around Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have some design requirements that are not supported by Entity Framework, but are easily met by a simple SQL Query.

[Essentially I need to do an insert that sets an Identity value.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405280/insert-an-identity-value-using-entity-framework)

Are there drawbacks to making a sproc that does my insert and then having EF call that sproc?

Are there caching concerns I need to be worried about?  (Because I will be updating data "behind EF's back".)

Are there concurrency issues?

Anything else I need to be worried about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't keep around your db context, i.e. you dispose it after every unit of work this should work just fine (this covers most web scenarios) - unless you concurrently operate on the same table - if that is the case you might want to use a lock to synchronize the SQL and the EF queries or catch `OptimisticConcurrencyException` thrown by EF.

If you do keep a context around on the other hand make sure that you refresh it with `RefreshMode.StoreWins`.

Also see ["Saving Changes and Managing Concurrency"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738618.aspx)